# Time complexity of n-vertex subgraph enumeration

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, time-complexity, subgraph

I have an algorithm for creating a list of all possible subgraphs on P vertices through a given vertex. It's not perfect
but I think it should be working alright. The problem is I get lost when I try to calculate its time complexity.

I conjured up something like `T(p) = 2^d + 2^d * (n * T(p-1) )`, where `d=Δ(G), p=#vertices required, n=|V|`. It's really just a guess.
Can anyone help me with this?

The powerSet() algorithm used should be `O(2^d)` or `O(d*2^d)`.

```
private void connectedGraphsOnNVertices(int n, Set<Node> connectedSoFar, Set<Node> neighbours, List<Set<Node>> graphList) {
    if (n==1) return;

    for (Set<Node> combination : powerSet(neighbours)) {
        if (connectedSoFar.size() + combination.size() > n || combination.size() == 0) {
            continue;
        } else if (connectedSoFar.size() + combination.size() == n) {
            Set<Node> newGraph = new HashSet<Node>();
            newGraph.addAll(connectedSoFar);
            newGraph.addAll(combination);
            graphList.add(newGraph);
            continue;
        }

        connectedSoFar.addAll(combination);
        for (Node node: combination) {
            Set<Node> k = new HashSet<Node>(node.getNeighbours());
            connectedGraphsOnNVertices(n, connectedSoFar, k, graphList);
        }
        connectedSoFar.removeAll(combination);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the algorithm has a bug because after the recursive call, it is possible that nodes that appear in combination also appear in connectedSoFar, so the check that connectedSoFar.size() + combination.size() equals n seems incorrect, as it might count a node twice.

Anyway, otherwise to analyze the algorithm, you have 2<sup>d</sup> elements in the powerset; every operation in the "elase" branch takes O(n) time because connectedSoFar and combination together can't contain more than n nodes. Adding elements to connectedSoFar then takes O(n log n) time because |combination| ≤ n. The iteration over combination nodes happens O(n) times; within it there is O(d) operation to construct the hash set k and then recursive call.

Denote then the complexity of the procedure by X(n) where n is the parameter. You have

X(n) ~ 2<sup>d</sup> (n + n log n + n (d + X(n - 1)))

because in the recursive call you have added at least one vertex to the graph so in practice the parameter n in the recursive call decreases virtually by at least one.

Simplify this to

X(n) ~ 2<sup>d</sup> (n (1 + d + log n + X(n - 1)))

because d is constant, mark D = 2<sup>d</sup>, eliminate the constant 1, and you get

X(n) ~ D n (d + log n + X(n - 1))

which you can analyze as

X(n) ~ (2<sup>d</sup>)<sup>n</sup> n! (d + log n)

showing that your algorithm is really a time hog :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this in-depth analysis! Looks like it really is a time hog, luckily I don't need it to be very efficient - but perhaps someone here can point me to a better way of doing this. Thanks again.